# Problem with GWT behind a reverse proxy - either nginx or apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, gwt

I originally [asked this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517290/problem-with-gwt-behind-a-reverse-proxy-either-nginx-or-apache), but perhaps SF is a better place for traction on this question.

I'm having this problem with GWT when it's behind a reverse proxy.  The backend app is deployed within a context - let's call it /context.

The GWT app works fine when I hit it directly:

http://host:8080/context/

I can configure a reverse proxy in front it it.  Here's my nginx example:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

...

location / {
   proxy_pass        http://backend/context/;
}
```

But, when I run through the reverse proxy, GWT gets confused, saying:

```
2009-10-04 14:05:41.140:/:WARN:  Login: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/C7F5ECA5E3C10B453290DE47D3BE0F0E.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?
2009-10-04 14:05:41.140:/:WARN:  Login: WARNING: Failed to get the SerializationPolicy 'C7F5ECA5E3C10B453290DE47D3BE0F0E' for module 'https://hostname:444/'; a legacy, 1.3.3 compatible, serialization policy will be used.  You may experience SerializationExceptions as a result.
2009-10-04 14:05:41.292:/:WARN:  StoryService: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/0445C2D48AEF2FB8CB70C4D4A7849D88.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?
2009-10-04 14:05:41.292:/:WARN:  StoryService: WARNING: Failed to get the SerializationPolicy '0445C2D48AEF2FB8CB70C4D4A7849D88' for module 'https://hostname:444/'; a legacy, 1.3.3 compatible, serialization policy will be used.  You may experience SerializationExceptions as a result.
```

In other words, GWT isn't getting the word that it needs to prepend /context/ then look for C7F5ECA5E3C10B453290DE47D3BE0F0E.gwt.rpc, but only when the request comes throught proxy.  A workaround is to add the context to the url for the web site:

```
location /context/ {
    proxy_pass        http://backend/context/;
}
```

but that means the context is now part of the url that the user sees, and that's ugly.

Anybody know how to make GWT happy in this case?

Software versions:
GWT - 1.7.0 (same problem with 1.7.1)
Jetty - 6.1.21 (but the same problem existed under tomcat)
nginx - 0.7.62 (same problem under apache 2.x)

My suspicion is that perhaps GWT is picking up on the Referer header, and getting confused (is there a way for nginx to turn off that header?) or that there's a difference since the traffic between the proxy and GWT/Jetty is HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should

```
location /context/ {
    proxy_pass        http://backend/context/;
}
```

and then use rewrite to strip /context part from URL

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out, but it finally dawned on me that my problem was that I was doing the rewrite in the location context, and it needed to be in the server context:

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /stuff/$1;

        location /stuff/ {
            proxy_pass        http://backend/stuff/;
        }

Comment: Scratch that - it didn't fix the problem.  Maybe it really is a GWT bug.

Comment: i think nginx has some different behavior depending on closing slashes in proxy_pass directive, so you can play with it